# Why does Geronimo Javamail not fetch the message subject and collides with default JVM implementation?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

In our continuous integration we had a test failure because a new email sent during the test would not be downloaded. Digging down to the problem and enabling javamail debug we found out that locally

> DEBUG: getProvider() returning
>   javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle]

while on the CI

> DEBUG: getProvider() returning provider protocol=pop3s;
>   type=javax.mail.Provider$Type@728749b3;
>   class=org.apache.geronimo.javamail.store.pop3.POP3SSLStore;
>   vendor=Apache Software Foundation;version=1.0

This is what our investigation us:

- Even if you are using the same version of SBT and a different minor of Java, you can't rely on classloading to behave the same
- Javamail allows you to specifically force a property for each store class, by setting `mail.pop3s.class` one can override the behaviour and force the usage of the `Pop3SSLStore`.
- Even with this setting, the message subject is not fetched in the CI when we do `message.getSubject` which always returns null. Enabling javamail debugging shows that no TOP command is ever executed on the CI, while it is executelly locally. So messages are not retrieved from the server
- Excluding explicitly all the dependencies from "org.apache.geronimo.javamail" solves the problem

Why would one use Geronimo, and why does it mess up with the default jvm implementation that works so well on our machine?

Comment: Geronimo is an application server in a similar vein to Jboss. Just as JBoss has a default JMS Provider (JBossMQ/HornetQ etc), Geronimo has a default JavaMail implementation which it provides. I am guessing you'd choose to use theirs over the reference implementation because it ties up nicely with other features (e.g. management, alerting) inside Geronimo. Why it fails to download new emails vs. the reference implementation? Guessing it's buried in the configuration as it so often is with these things :(

Comment: We are still struggling, even when using the mail.pop3.class and using the default POP3SSLStore, the messages are not fetched ( getSubject returns null)

Comment: Are you actually running in the Geronimo application server?  Or did you just end up with that implementation of the JavaMail APIs because it was installed into your JDK runtime on your Linux system?  If the latter, jsut remove it and use the JavaMail reference implementation.

Comment: Thanks @BillShannon, we considered that but the problem is that if other apps we build on the same CI use the same library, it will be pulled again

Comment: Without knowing where and how you're running your app, it's hard to give you any more advice about what to do.